# rearranging words in the header dataframe

Tags: pandas, header

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'FY18Q1': [ 1500, 1200, 950, 2200], 
'FY18Q2': [ 2340, 1234, 2000, 1230],
'FY18Q3': [2130, 2200, 2190, 2210],   
'FY18YearTotal': [1000, 1900, 1500, 1800]})
```

I wish to re-arrange the order of the header. I want to the header to read '1Q18' where it does 'FY181Q' and 'FY18' where it reads 'FY18YearTotal'

I can drop the 'FY' and 'YearTotal' by:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"(|FY|\.)", "")
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"(|YearTotal|\.)", "")
```

But it does not get me to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'1Q18': [ 1500, 1200, 950, 2200], 
'2Q18': [ 2340, 1234, 2000, 1230],
'3Q18': [2130, 2200, 2190, 2210],   
'FY18': [1000, 1900, 1500, 1800]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply chain two calls to `str.replace` here:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'^FY(\d+)Q(\d+)', r'\2Q\1', regex=True)
                       .str.replace(r'YearTotal$', r'', regex=True)
```

Comment: very nice, I couldn't think of a way to do it in a single regex (unless you wrap it in a lambda with an if/else but looks ugly) nice use of capturing groups.

Comment: @Umar.H Yes -- we could use `apply()` with a lambda function, but then the replacement logic would be verbose.  I prefer 2 separate replacements in this case, as they are non conflicting.